# How can I draw polygons on google maps flutter at my current position as I move My device-Live Location Tracing

Tags: flutter, google-maps

While there exist a variety or recourses already talking about something close to this, I mean this. I want to dynamically trace say a small forest/Building as I go around it live on google maps, I.e., If I stand at the edge of a building in the field with my phone (With my `currentlocationenabled: true`), I can trace the building from start to end and come back and close it at the starting point. Currently, I can draw any polygon anywhere on the map, but I want a dynamic one: When I go to the edge of a building I call the `drawPolygonNow()`, then so on and so on. My current sample code, that was guided by [this resource](https://medium.com/@zeh.henrique92/google-maps-flutter-marker-circle-and-polygon-c71f4ea64498):

```
class _MyMapScreenState extends State<MyMapScreen> {
    LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(userCurrentPosition!.latitude, userCurrentPosition!.longitude);
    /* Data: Add point markers, lines, polygons */
    Set<Marker> _markers = {};
    Set<Polygon> _polygons = HashSet<Polygon>();
    List<LatLng> polygonLatLngs1 = <LatLng>[];   
    
    // Draw Polygon
    void _drawPolygon(LatLng latLngPosition) {
        final String polygonIdVal = 'Area ID_$_polygonIdCounter';
        _polygons.add(Polygon(
            polygonId: PolygonId("1"),
            points: polygonLatLngs1,
            strokeWidth: 2,
            strokeColor: strokeColor,
            fillColor: fillColor
        ));
    
        body: Stack(
            children[
                GoogleMp(
                    polygons: _polygons,
                    onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
                    onTap: (latLngPosition) {
                        if (_isPolygon) {
                            setState(() {
                                polygonLatLngs1.add(latLngPosition);
                                _drawPolygon(latLngPosition);
                            });
                        } 
                    },
                ...
```